# How can I center the hint text in a DropdownButtonFormField?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I'd like to center the hint text in my form field. How can I achieve this?

I've tried using an `Align` widget, but that's not working.

Here's my current code:

```
List<String> options = [
    'Main room',
    'Side Room',
    'Bathroom(lol)',
    'Back Room',
  ];

DropdownButtonFormField<String>(
   decoration: InputDecoration(enabledBorder: InputBorder.none),
    items: options.map((String value) {
      return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
        value: value,
        child: Align(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: Text(value, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20))),
      );
    }).toList(),
    isDense: true,
    isExpanded: false,
    hint: Align(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: Text(options[0], style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20))),
    onChanged: (_) {},
  )
```

From this, I'd expect the text to be centered, but it comes out like this:

[Current dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PUxDS.png)

Comment: Let me know if the answer helps!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to change the **`isExpanded: true`**

**Final Code:**

```
DropdownButtonFormField<String>(
  decoration: InputDecoration(enabledBorder: InputBorder.none),
  items: options.map((String value) {
    return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
      value: value,
      child: Align(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: Text(value, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20))),
    );
  }).toList(),
  isDense: true,
  isExpanded: true,
  hint: Align(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      child: Text(options[0], style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20))),
  onChanged: (_) {},
)
```